# Missing GULSwizzler.h file

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I've upgraded an iOS/Swift project to the latest Firebase pods.
The following changes were made:

- Firebase 5.11.0 (was 5.10.0)
- FirebaseAnalytics 5.3.0 (was 5.2.0)
- FirebaseCore 5.1.6 (was 5.1.5)
- FirebaseInstanceID 3.3.0 (was 3.2.2)
- GoogleAppMeasurement 5.3.0 (was 5.2.0)
- GoogleUtilities 5.3.4 (was 5.3.3)
- nanopb 0.3.901 (was 0.3.8)

I'm getting an error on a missing file that's imported in GoogleUtilities at build time:

```
'Private/GULSwizzler.h' file not found
```

My pod import file has the following:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
pod 'GoogleSymbolUtilities'
pod 'GoogleInterchangeUtilities'
```

Has anyone come across this or know a solution?

******************************** edit **********************************
What I see under GoogleUtilities is shown below.  I note that the .h symbol is dimmed for the file that's missing.
[image]

Comment: What's the deployment target of your Xcode project? Can you post your whole podfile code too?

Comment: It's a project running on iOS10 and higher.  I'm using the newest Xcode and testing on the simulator.  I'll add an edit to show what I see under GoogleUtilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that GULSwizzler.h is not installed properly. For me, it is installed in a different location:

```
 $ find . | grep GULSwizzler.h
./Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler/Private/GULSwizzler.h
```

Here are a few things to try:

- Reinstall from a clean environment: `pod deintegrate` and `pod install`
- Make sure you have the latest version of CocoaPods:

  `$ pod --version
  1.5.3`

Probably unrelated, but strange: `GoogleSymbolUtilities` and `GoogleInterchangeUtilities` are deprecated private pods that were never intended to be added to Podfiles.

Comment: Hi Paul.  It seems that the file was missing following the last pod update.  I've deintegrated and installed again as you suggested and the file installed correctly this time.  I also removed the two pods you mentioned and everything works fine.  Thanks for all your help and tips.